# Incorect syntax near table when trying to save a stored procedure in C#

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created the following 3 tables for a database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Buyer] (
    [Buyer_Id]   INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Last_Name]  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [First_Name] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Social_No]  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Phone]      NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [User_Id]    INT           NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Buyer_Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_User_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([User_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([User_Id])
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Type] (
    [Type_Id]   INT        IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Type_Name] NCHAR (10) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Type_Id] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User] (
    [User_Id] INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [User_Name]    NCHAR (10)    NOT NULL,
    [Pass]    NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Type_Id] INT           NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([User_Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK__Type_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Type_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Type] ([Type_Id])
);
```

and I want to make a stored procedure with the purpose to be used in my Addcustumer Form in C#.

Bellow it is the code form my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertCustomer]
    @Buyer_Id int output,
    @Last_Name varchar(50),
    @Fist_Name varchar(50),
    @Social_No varchar(50),
    @Phone varchar(50),
    @User_Id int output,
    @User_Name nchar(10),
    @Pass varchar(50),
    @Type_id int output,
    @Type_Name nchar(10)

AS

    insert into Buyer(Buyer_Id,Last_Name,First_Name,Social_No,Phone)
    values (@Last_Name,@Fist_Name,@Social_No)
    set @Buyer_Id=SCOPE_IDENTITY

    insert into User(User_Name,Pass,Type_Id)
    values(@User_Id,@Pass)
    set @Type_id=SCOPE_IDENTITY

    insert into Type(Type_Id,Type_Name)
    values (@Type_Name)
    set @Type_id=SCOPE_IDENTITY

RETURN 0
```

But when I am trying to run my sql stored procedure I get the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'User'

Please tell what is wrong with my code.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual: User is a [reserved word in T-SQL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx). So you got to quote it:

```
insert into [User] (User_Name,Pass,Type_Id)
```

Comment: TYPE is also a key word

Comment: @M.Ali I was economical, I only read until I got to the unquoted `User` ... I should have been as thoroughly as you. Your answer is the better one!

Comment: Have you applied all fixes that @M.Ali mentioned? And what errors do you get?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of issues with your procedure. Yes what VMai has mentioned is very important and you also have the following errors.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertCustomer]
    @Buyer_Id int output,
    @Last_Name varchar(50),
    @Fist_Name varchar(50),
    @Social_No varchar(50),
    @Phone varchar(50),
    @User_Id int output,
    @User_Name nchar(10),
    @Pass varchar(50),
    @Type_id int output,
    @Type_Name nchar(10)

AS
 BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;  --<-- to suppress the default sql server message (N) row(s) effected. 

    insert into Buyer(Buyer_Id,Last_Name,First_Name,Social_No,Phone)
    values (@Last_Name,@Fist_Name,@Social_No)
    set @Buyer_Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();   --<-- Missing Parenthesis 

    insert into [User](User_Name,Pass,Type_Id)
    values(@User_Id,@Pass)
    set @User_Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();  --<-- Missing Parenthesis  and I think 
                                         --it was suppose to be @User_Id

    insert into [Type](Type_Id,Type_Name)
    values (@Type_Name)
    set @Type_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();    --<-- Missing Parenthesis 

    RETURN 0

 END
```

Comment: To me this should be accepted as answer for it's detail error pointing.

Comment: :) @Rahul not many new users understand how Accepting an answer works and how it should be used. After all this was OP's first question on SO, I remember when I joined SO for quite sometime I could'nt figure out how to format a question or an answer :)

Comment: LOL ... a +1 from me for a nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertCustomer]
    @Buyer_Id int output,
    @Last_Name varchar(50),
    @Fist_Name varchar(50),
    @Social_No varchar(50),
    @Phone varchar(50),
    @User_Id int output,
    @User_Name nchar(10),
    @Pass varchar(50),
    @Type_id int output,
    @Type_Name nchar(10)

AS

    insert into Buyer(Buyer_Id,Last_Name,First_Name,Social_No,Phone)
    values (@Last_Name,@Fist_Name,@Social_No)
    set @Buyer_Id=SCOPE_IDENTITY

    insert into User(User_Name,Pass,Type_Id)
    values(@User_Id,@Pass)
    set @Type_id=SCOPE_IDENTITY

    insert into Type(Type_Id,Type_Name)
    values (@Type_Name)
    set @Type_id=SCOPE_IDENTITY

RETURN 0
```

in above code :

```
insert into User(User_Name,Pass,Type_Id)
        values(@User_Id,@Pass)
        set @Type_id=SCOPE_IDENTITY
```

replace with

```
insert into [User] (User_Name,Pass,Type_Id)
        values(@User_Id,@Pass)
        set @Type_id=SCOPE_IDENTITY
```

because user is a reserved word that's why your are getting error. to avoid this use quote.